# only 404s returned when using ngrok for kik

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404, bots, ngrok

I'm trying to develop a kik bot. I used ngrok to tunnel my localhost to a ngrok server. However, whenever I run my python program and start the ngrok server and message the bot on my phone, all it returns are 404 errors. Here is my python code

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import os 
from kik import KikApi, Configuration 
from kik.messages import messages_from_json, TextMessage

app = Flask(__name__)
BOT_USERNAME = os.environ.get('BOT_USERNAME') 
BOT_API_KEY =  os.environ.get('BOT_API_KEY') 

kik = KikApi(BOT_USERNAME, BOT_API_KEY)

kik.set_configuration(Configuration(webhook='my_webhook'))

@app.route('/incoming', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    if not kik.verify_signature(request.headers.get('X-Kik-Signature'),    request.get_data()):
    return Response(status=403) 

    messages = messages_from_json(request.json['messages'])

    for message in messages:
        if isinstance(message, TextMessage):
            kik.send_messages([
                TextMessage(
                    to=message.from_user,
                    chat_id=message.chat_id,
                    body=message.body
                )
            ])

return Response(status=200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

Basically, when I run this file, ngrok and the localhost tell me "404 not found". I followed the directions [here](https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#api-authentication-with-webhook-endpoint) and made a POST to set up my bot's configuration. When I check the kik bot for the webhook, it shows the ngrok url. Is there something else I need to do to be able to send messages to the bot as a normal user? I know the kik authenticates using the "X-Kik-Username", so does that have something to do with it?

[Error messages from ngrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4vne.png)

Comment: After running this, how are you trying to access it?

Comment: @lennard I just message the bot on my phone

Comment: Can you show the error message your getting please?

Comment: @lennard sure, I added the error message that ngrok is giving me whenever I send a message to the bot on my phone

Comment: Ok so it looks like ngrok is sending a POST to `/` when your route is `/incoming`. Try changing it to match.

Comment: @lennard How do I change the route in ngrok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed the route in the code from "/incoming" to "/". That allowed for the right response.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using Django with 404s because the webhook URL specified in the external platform was included in the request to local dev server by ngrok, so something like http://xyz.ngrok.io/https://xyz.ngrok.io/api/v1/webhooks was used as request. Using -host-header option solved it for me:

```
./ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 127.0.0.1:8000
```